# Recovering error tokens in parsing (Lemon)

Tags: c, parsing, token, yacc, lemon

I'm using Lemon as a parser generator, its error handling is the same as yacc's and bison's if you don't know Lemon.

Lemon has an option to define the error token in a set of rules in order to catch parsing errors. The default behavior of the generated parser is to destroy the token causing the error; is there any way to override this behavior so that I can keep the token?

Here's an example to show what's happening: basically I'm appending the tokens for each rule together to reform the input string, here's an example grammar:

```
input ::= string(A) { printf("%s", A); } // Print the result
string(A) ::= string(B) part(C). { A = append(B, C); }
string(A) ::= part(B). { A = B; }
part(A) ::= NUMBER(B) NAME(C). { A = append(C, B); } // Rearrange the number and name
part(A) ::= error(B). { A = B; } // On error keep the token anyways
```

On input:

```
"Username 1234Joseph"
```

I get output:

```
"Joseph1234"
```

Because the text "Username " is junked by the parser in the part(A) ::= error(B) rule, but I really want:

```
"Username Joseph1234"
```

as output.

If you can solve this problem in bison or another parser generator I would accept that as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With yacc/bison, a parsing error drops the tool into error recovery mode, if possible. It will attempt to discard tokens on its way to a "clean" state.

I'm unable to find a reference for lemon, so I can't show some lemon code to fix this, but with yacc/bison, one would use the rules [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Recovery.html#Error-Recovery).

Namely, you need to adjust your error rule to state that the parser is ok with `yyerrok` to prevent it from dropping tokens. Next, it will attempt to reread the "bad" token, so you need to clear it with `yyclearin`. Finally, since the rule attached to your error code contains the contents of your token, you will need to set up a function that adjusts your input stack, by taking the current token contents and creating a new (proper) token with the same contents.

As an example, if a grammar defined as MyOther MyOther saw MyTok MyOther:

```
stack
MyTok: "the text"
MyOther: "new text"

stack
MyOther: "the text"
MyOther: "new text"
```

To accomplish this, look into using [yybackup](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Action-Features.html#Action-Features). I'm unable to find an alternative method, though `yybackup` is frowned upon.

Comment: In case anyone was interested I ended up switching over to RE2C [[link](http://re2c.org/)]. It was much easier to get the behaviour with RE2C macros. I wrote the macros so that any unmatched substrings are simply output while any matched substrings are modified by RE2C.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old one, but why not...

The grammar must include spaces. At the moment the grammar only allows a sequence of NUMBER NAME tokens (without any space between the tokens).

Comment: There are badges (Necromancer and Revival) for answering old questions and getting up votes, so there's every reason to answer older questions without an answer (or without a good answer).

Comment: The lexical analyzer presumably deals with spaces between tokens, etc.  That is a standard division of labour - the lexical analyzer handles comments and blanks and strings; the grammar deals with the tokens found by the lexical analyzer that are not eaten by it.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, I couldn't make that assumption based on the question. The token sequence NUMBER NAME is expected to catch 1234Joseph, but usually that would not be the case (1234Joseph would not be a legal token). I hope you see what I mean with respect to spaces.

Comment: fair enough - without knowing how the lexical analyzer analyzes stuff, it is hard to be sure what is going on.